# to_time gives argument out of range error Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, time

"35 mins ago".to_time gives "argument out of range" error while "30 mins ago".to_time does not. 
How to convert "35 mins ago" into time?

Comment: Please place your code.

Comment: `35.minutes.ago.to_time` Please ensure your code be like this!

Comment: How to convert "35 minutes ago" string into 35.minutes.ago.to_time and save in a variable ?

Comment: Time.now.advance(minutes: -35)